# How to avoid local and remote repos to be out of sync causing non-fast-forward errors

Tags: git, github

I set up and use a fork repo (called origin) of an open source project (called upstream) on GitHub. Before trying to push my local changes to remote I first update the repo on my local machine using the following commands:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git rebase upstream/master
```

As I am the only one using the branch I use rebase to keep a clean log history. I then sync the remote fork master branch with my local one using

```
git push origin master
```

This was to get local and remote master branches up to date. In order to prepare the working branch for a later push I switch to it by doing a checkout and rebasing it with upstream or origin (due to the sync before they are the same):

```
git checkout branchname

git rebase upstream/master 
*or*
git rebase origin/master
```

Then when I do a

```
git push origin geom_utils_enhancements
```

I get a fast-forward-error stating the current branch and its external counterpart are out of sync.

Comparing the logs using `git log` and `git log origin/branchname` I can see a diversion at the HEAD where the local branch has been updated by the rebase and the remote has not.

How can I avoid getting into this state and how can I solve it? Up to now I tried solving it 'resetting' the remote branch to a earlier state using `git push origin abcdefg-hash:branchname` and followed by a rebase. This can't be the regular way to go.

Would maybe a `git merge origin/master` instead of the rebase on the branch be a smarter thing to do? If so, why?

Comment: Do not try to avoid this. This is a fundamental part of how git works. Please try instead to get used to merging, or rebasing.

Comment: I am not sure if I was able to explain myself well. When I did a rebase earlier and later end up in a state out of sync that needs to get fixed by a 'git push origin abcdefg-hash:branchname' followed by another push - is this really the way to go?

Comment: If you know that `origin/branchname` needs to be rebased onto `origin/master`, like you did in your local sandbox, the next step I would do is a forced push: `git push -f origin branchname`. Using a rebase workflow on pushed branches requires forced pushing them afterwards. As long as you're the only user of that branch, no one will complain about those forced pushes.

Comment: And yes, once you've done a rebase locally, the results cannot be fast-forward pushed, because any (non-trivial) rebase operation creates a divergence between the two branches.

Answer (score 0):

Rebase works, fundamentally, by *copying and then abandoning* some set of existing commits.  That is, we might start with:

```
...--o--o--*--D--E--F    <-- branch-A
            \
             A--B--C   <-- branch-B (HEAD)
```

indicating that you're currently on `branch-B`, which has three commits `A-B-C` that are not also on `branch-A` (plus commit `*` and all earlier commits that *are* on `branch-A`; commits `D-E-F` are *only* on `branch-A` at this time).  You then decide that commits `A-B-C` are good, but not good *enough:* there is something you don't like about them.  This may be as simple as *they don't come after commit `F`*, or it may be something more complicated, but either way, you choose now to *copy* `A-B-C` to new and improved commits.  You may make as many changes as you like along the way: for instance, you might fix some typos in some commit messages, or combine commits `A` and `C` into a single commit with commit `B` coming after it.  Or you might leave all three mostly as-is.

For argument's sake, let's combine `A` and `C` into a single `AC` commit and copy `B` as is to a new commit `B'` that comes after the combined `AC` commit.  The resulting *commit graph* looks like this:

```
                      AC-B'
                     /
...--o--o--*--D--E--F
            \
             A--B--C
```

Note that I have removed the labels—the branch names—from this graph.  That's because *they are not necessary*.  Git isn't about *branches;* Git is about *commits*.  All we need are the commits themselves.

There is a problem though, if we remove all the names.  The commits themselves are found by raw hash IDs: big, ugly, random-looking hash IDs, [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers that no human could ever remember.  We need to have Git assist us by keeping—in branch names—a mapping: The name `branch-A` holds the big ugly hash ID of the *last commit* that we want to claim to be part of `branch-A`.  Meanwhile the name `branch-B` holds the big ugly hash ID of the *last commit* that we want to claim to be part of `branch-B`.  So we need the *names* to go like this:

```
                      AC-B'  <-- branch-B
                     /
...--o--o--*--D--E--F   <-- branch-A
            \
             A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

With no *name* by which to *find* commit `C`, we won't see it.  Git will retain it for a while, but eventually Git will see that we not only can't *see* it, but aren't ever going to ask Git to *get it back for us*,<sup>1</sup> and Git will then remove it on its own.

But this action—this *copy commits `A-B-C` to new and improved versions, then abandon the originals by yanking the branch names around* thing we do with `git rebase`—happens *only in our own local repository*, not in another repository copy over on GitHub or some other host.  So when we go to `git push origin branch-B`, *that* Git says: *Hold on there!  If I take your `AC-B'` commits and remember `B'` as the last commit, I'll lose my `A-B-C` commits off my `branch-B`!  So no, I won't do that, no sir!*

We, of course, *want* that Git to do exactly that: our new `B'` commit is our *improved replacement* for `B`, and its `AC` parent is our *improved replacement* for `A`-and-`C`.  But we don't have a way to say that.  All he—the other Git—knows is that we're telling him to drop commits from *his* `branch-B`.  (Note that *his* branches are *his:* they're entirely separate from our branches, even if they may be spelled the same.  It's the *commits* that we share, not the branch names.)

So, if we really want him to drop his `A-B-C` commits in favor of our new improved `AC-B'` chain, we must use `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease` or similar.  That tells him: *Yes, I know this will lose some commits; do it anyway.*  He's still free to say no, but if we sees us as the "owner" of his Git repository, he'll probably obey our force-push.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git keeps these emergency backup *whoa I didn't mean to do that, get my commits back for me!* things around for a minimum of 30 days by default, with 90 days for other cases.  If we haven't panicked and had Git go get them back, Git drops the emergency backup references, and then `git gc`—a maintenance command that Git runs on its own now and then for us—will erase the leftover junk.

---

#### Merge vs rebase

> Would maybe a `git merge origin/master` instead of the rebase on the branch be a smarter thing to do?

This is a matter of opinion.  Merge and rebase are *different actions*.  Rebase means "replace some existing commits with new and improved commits" while merge means "combine work in two sets of existing commits by adding one new commit".  There is one special case here, the *fast forward* merge, which is best shown by illustration.

Here's a normal everyday merge setup:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch-2
```

We are on `branch-1`, having made two commits `I` and `J` atop commit `H`.  They (whoever they are) *also* made two commits atop `H`, which we're calling `K` and `L` and finding with the name `branch-2`.

Each commit holds a full snapshot of all files, plus the usual metadata.  Our commits `I` and `J` have some files changed vs their parents `H` and `I` respectively, but a simple `git diff hash-of-H hash-of-J` will find, for Git, exactly what we changed: what *changes* we made to *which files*.  All other files in `H` are unchanged through `I` and `J`.

Meanwhile, a simple `git diff hash-of-H hash-of-L` will do the same for their commits: any files *not* changed from `H` are exactly the same all the way through all three commits, and for the files that *are* changed, this diff listing will show what changed.

Git can therefore:

- extract all the files from `H`;
- apply all *our* changes, to keep our stuff; and
- apply all *their* changes, to keep *their* stuff too

and where the changes are to different files, or different lines within the same files, Git can just assume that the changes don't conflict.  If the changes touch the *same* lines, or butt up against each other (touch adjacent lines), Git will assume that the changes *do* conflict, with one special case: if we and they made the *exact same* changes to the *same* lines, Git will just take *one copy* of those changes.

Those are the rules for `git merge`: combine changes where possible, or declare a conflict where that's impossible.  Then, if all changes got combined, make a new commit, with the snapshot being the result of applying the combined changes to the files from the *merge base*—the common starting point, which in this case is commit `H`.  So if all goes well, we get:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch-2
```

This new *merge commit* `M` goes on our current branch in the usual way: by making the branch name, in this case `branch-1`, point to the new commit, which points back to what used to be the last commit on that branch, i.e., `J`.  The only thing special about merge commit `M` is that it *also* points back to commit `L`.  In other words, it has *two* parents instead of the usual single parent.

Note that commit `M` gets a new, random-looking hash ID as usual.  However, no *existing* commit has changed, and all we did was *add a commit to one branch*, `branch-1` in this case.  This had the odd side effect of causing two more commits `K-L` to be included in `branch-1` as well (without removing them from `branch-2`, which continues to name commit `L` directly).

Because new commit `M` *adds on* to `branch-1`, we can `git push` this to another Git repository and tell them to make it *their* final `branch-1` commit, without losing anything from their repository either.  (This assumes they haven't gained some new commit `N` since then of course.)  So merge is "less damaging", in some sense, than rebase.

#### Fast-forward merge

The special case of merge that I mentioned above occurs when we have branches that go like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-2
         /
...--G--H   <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
```

Here, we're on `branch-1`, which means we are using commit `H`.  "Their" branch `branch-2` refers to commit `J`.  If we run:

```
git merge branch-2
```

we are asking our Git to find the merge base—the best *shared* commit, on *both* branches—and compare that to our current commit and to their commit `J`.  But that best shared commit *is* our current commit `H`.  So if Git were to do a full-blown merge, it would diff commit `H` against commit `H` to see what we changed.

Obviously, the files in commit `H` match the files in commit `H`: we changed *nothing*.  Git would then compare the files in `H` against those in `J`, to see what *they* changed.  Git would then combine these changes—which results in "what they changed", whatever that is—and then apply those changes to the files in `H`.  The result is just the same as using the files in `J` directly.

If Git made a new merge commit `M` as a result, it would look like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-2
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- branch-1 (HEAD)
```

We *can* tell Git to do this!  We just run `git merge --no-ff branch-2`, and Git will go ahead and make new merge commit `M` as usual, on the current branch; it will have two parents, as a merge commit does; and it will *share all of its files* with commit `J` because Git will combine our work (nothing) with their work (producing commit `J`'s files), so the new snapshot will duplicate `J`'s files, and Git's de-duplication trick will cause the new commit to literally share the files directly.

But Git realizes that all this work is unnecessary: merge commit `M` *will* share all those files, and therefore it's possible to just *check out commit `J` directly* while also "sliding the branch name forward", like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-1 (HEAD), branch-2
         /
...--G--H
```

Git calls this a *fast-forward merge*, and uses it as a short-cut by default when we ask for this kind of merge.  We need the `--no-ff` flag to avoid it.

Should you avoid it, or use it?  That's a matter of opinion.  The key difference is whether we get that merge commit `M`, so that the two branch names point to *different commits*, or not, so that the two branch names *both point to a single commit* afterward.  If you allow a fast-forward merge, and stop drawing in the kink in the graph, you get:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- branch-1 (HEAD), branch-2
```

which many people find aesthetically pleasing.  So do that if you like it and have no reason to keep the merge commits.  Don't do that if you don't like it or have reason to keep the merge commits.